# como puedo hacer que un login en flutter al ingresar utilize los mismos datos que tengo en un api que yo cree

Tags: api, flutter, dart, login

Para un proyecto de la uni, la empresa me pidio una aplicacion movil para dispositivos IOS, entonces opte por utilizar Flutter/Dart, para esto solo me pidieron de mientras un login que es donde estoy atascado, para la creacion del login creé un api que muestra los siguientes datos (Tambien es la tabla de la base de datos):

```
CREATE TABLE `usuarios` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `apellidoM` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `apellidoP` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fechaN` date NOT NULL,
  `genero` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `usuario` varchar(45) NOT NULL, -- Nuevo campo usuario
  `contrasena` varchar(45) NOT NULL, -- Nuevo campo contraseña
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Asi es como me muestra los resultados en formato json:

```
[{"id":"4","nombre":"pedro","apellidoP":"pedro","apellidoM":"pedro","fechaN":"2023-08-08","genero":"m","usuario":"pedro1","contrasena":"pedro1"},{"id":"5","nombre":"oscar","apellidoP":"antunez","apellidoM":"roque","fechaN":"2023-08-08","genero":"m","usuario":"pruebau","contrasena":"pruebac"},{"id":"6","nombre":"luis","apellidoP":"luis","apellidoM":"luis","fechaN":"2023-08-08","genero":"m","usuario":"luis","contrasena":"luis"},{"id":"7","nombre":"jacinto","apellidoP":"jacinto","apellidoM":"jacinto","fechaN":"2023-08-08","genero":"m","usuario":"jacinto","contrasena":"jacinto"},{"id":"8","nombre":"andres","apellidoP":"andres","apellidoM":"andres","fechaN":"2003-04-12","genero":"M","usuario":"uno1","contrasena":""}]
```

El archivo de mi api tiene 2 carpetas:

Connection:
Con el archivo Connection.php

La carppeta Models:
Con el archivo Cliente.php que tiene lo siguiente:

```
<?php
require_once "connection/Connection.php";

class Cliente {

    public static function getAll() {
        $db = new Connection();
        $query = "SELECT * FROM usuarios";
        $resultado = $db->query($query);
        $datos = [];
        if($resultado->num_rows) {
            while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
                $datos[] = [
                    'id' => $row['id'],
                    'nombre' => $row['nombre'],
                    'apellidoP' => $row['apellidoP'],
                    'apellidoM' => $row['apellidoM'],
                    'fechaN' => $row['fechaN'],
                    'genero' => $row['genero'],
                    'usuario' => $row['usuario'],
                    'contrasena' => $row['contrasena']
                ];
            }
        }
        return $datos;
    }

    public static function getWhere($id_usuario) {
        $db = new Connection();
        $id_usuario = $db->real_escape_string($id_usuario);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id = $id_usuario";
        $resultado = $db->query($query);
        $datos = [];
        if($resultado->num_rows) {
            while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
                $datos[] = [
                    'id' => $row['id'],
                    'nombre' => $row['nombre'],
                    'apellidoP' => $row['apellidoP'],
                    'apellidoM' => $row['apellidoM'],
                    'fechaN' => $row['fechaN'],
                    'genero' => $row['genero'],
                    'usuario' => $row['usuario'],
                    'contrasena' => $row['contrasena']
                ];
            }
        }
        return $datos;
    }

    public static function insert($nombre, $apellidoP, $apellidoM, $fechaN, $genero, $usuario, $contrasena) {
        $db = new Connection();
        $nombre = $db->real_escape_string($nombre);
        $apellidoP = $db->real_escape_string($apellidoP);
        $apellidoM = $db->real_escape_string($apellidoM);
        $fechaN = $db->real_escape_string($fechaN);
        $genero = $db->real_escape_string($genero);
        $usuario = $db->real_escape_string($usuario);
        $contrasena = $db->real_escape_string($contrasena);
        
        $query = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre, apellidoP, apellidoM, fechaN, genero, usuario, contrasena)
        VALUES('$nombre', '$apellidoP', '$apellidoM', '$fechaN', '$genero', '$usuario', '$contrasena')";
        $db->query($query);
        if($db->affected_rows) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static function update($id_usuario, $nombre, $apellidoP, $apellidoM, $fechaN, $genero, $usuario, $contrasena) {
        $db = new Connection();
        $id_usuario = $db->real_escape_string($id_usuario);
        $nombre = $db->real_escape_string($nombre);
        $apellidoP = $db->real_escape_string($apellidoP);
        $apellidoM = $db->real_escape_string($apellidoM);
        $fechaN = $db->real_escape_string($fechaN);
        $genero = $db->real_escape_string($genero);
        $usuario = $db->real_escape_string($usuario);
        $contrasena = $db->real_escape_string($contrasena);
        
        $query = "UPDATE usuarios SET
        nombre='$nombre', apellidoP='$apellidoP', apellidoM='$apellidoM', fechaN='$fechaN', genero='$genero',
        usuario='$usuario', contrasena='$contrasena'
        WHERE id = $id_usuario";
        $db->query($query);
        if($db->affected_rows) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static function delete($id_usuario) {
        $db = new Connection();
        $id_usuario = $db->real_escape_string($id_usuario);
        
        $query = "DELETE FROM usuarios WHERE id = $id_usuario";
        $db->query($query);
        if($db->affected_rows) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

Y afuera de las carpetas 2 codigos:

api_rest.sql:

```
-- MariaDB dump 10.19  Distrib 10.4.24-MariaDB, for Win64 (AMD64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: api_rest
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   10.4.24-MariaDB

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `usuarios`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `usuarios`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `usuarios` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `apellidoM` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `apellidoP` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fechaN` date NOT NULL,
  `genero` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `usuario` varchar(45) NOT NULL, -- Nuevo campo usuario
  `contrasena` varchar(45) NOT NULL, -- Nuevo campo contraseña
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2023-06-23 16:27:26
```

Y el index:

```
<?php
require_once "models/Cliente.php";

header("Content-Type: application/json");

switch ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
    case 'GET':
        if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
            $data = Cliente::getWhere($_GET['id']);
        } else {
            $data = Cliente::getAll();
        }

        echo json_encode($data);
        break;
    case 'POST':
        $datos = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
        if($datos != NULL) {
            if(Cliente::insert($datos->nombre, $datos->apellidoP, $datos->apellidoM, $datos->fechaN, $datos->genero, $datos->usuario, $datos->contrasena)) {
                http_response_code(200);
            } else {
                http_response_code(400);
            }
        } else {
            http_response_code(405);
        }
        break;
    case 'PUT':
        $datos = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
        if($datos != NULL) {
            if(Cliente::update($datos->id, $datos->nombre, $datos->apellidoP, $datos->apellidoM, $datos->fechaN, $datos->genero, $datos->usuario, $datos->contrasena)) {
                http_response_code(200);
            } else {
                http_response_code(400);
            }
        } else {
            http_response_code(405);
        }
        break;
    case 'DELETE':
        if(isset($_GET['id'])){
            if(Cliente::delete($_GET['id'])) {
                http_response_code(200);
            } else {
                http_response_code(400);
            }
        } else {
            http_response_code(405);
        }
        break;
    default:
        http_response_code(405);
        break;
}
?>
```

Aqui estan mis archivos de la aplicacion de flutter:

3 archivos:

main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'login_page.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: LoginPage(),
  ));
}
```

Archivo login_page.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'index.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  String _username = '';
  String _password = '';

  void _submitForm() {
    // Aquí puedes realizar la lógica de autenticación y validación de usuario y contraseña
    // Por ahora, solo mostraremos los datos ingresados en la consola
    print('Usuario: $_username');
    print('Contraseña: $_password');
    Navigator.push(
        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DataPage()));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Inicio de sesión'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  _username = value;
                });
              },
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Usuario',
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 16.0),
            TextField(
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  _password = value;
                });
              },
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Contraseña',
              ),
              obscureText: true,
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 24.0),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _submitForm,
              child: Text('Iniciar sesión'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

y el index.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class DataPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DataPageState createState() => _DataPageState();
}

class _DataPageState extends State<DataPage> {
  List<dynamic> _data = [];

  Future<void> fetchData() async {
    final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse('ejemplo para ocultar url'),
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final responseData = json.decode(response.body) as List<dynamic>;
      // ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison
      if (responseData != null) {
        setState(() {
          _data = responseData;
        });
      } else {
        throw Exception('La respuesta de la API es nula');
      }
    } else {
      throw Exception('Error al cargar los datos de la API');
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Consulta de API'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Datos de la API:', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0)),
            SizedBox(height: 10.0),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: _data.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  final dato = _data[index];

                  return Card(
                    margin:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 20.0),
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text(
                        'Nombre: ${dato['nombre'] ?? 'Nombre no disponible'}',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                      ),
                      subtitle: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            'ID: ${dato['id'] ?? 'ID no disponible'}',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'Apellido Paterno: ${dato['apellidoP'] ?? 'Apellido Paterno no disponible'}',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'Apellido Materno: ${dato['apellidoM'] ?? 'Apellido Materno no disponible'}',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'Fecha de Nacimiento: ${dato['fechaN'] ?? 'Fecha de Nacimiento no disponible'}',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'Género: ${dato['genero'] ?? 'Género no disponible'}',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'Usuario: ${dato['usuario'] ?? 'Usuario no disponible'}',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'Contraseña: ${dato['contrasena'] ?? 'Contraseña no disponible'}',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Lo que quiero que haga mi aplicacion es que con los usuarios y contraseñas que agrego a la api, con esos mismos usuarios y contraseños se validen y pueda acceder mediante el login, ahora, un compañero me dijo que ahora tendria que hacer otra api para el login que valide si existe el usuario y contraseña, este me tiene que devolver un 200 en postman y la informacion del usuario, en la aplicacion si quito el login solo para que se sepa, se muestra un listado de los datos que tengo agregado en el api, si pudiera alguien ayudarme o ponerse en contacto conmigo porfavor

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Te invito a hacer el [tour]. El sistema originalmente te pide más texto, no para que trates de burlarlo, sino para lograr una descripción de tu problema. Las preguntas que tienen solo código suelen ser de baja calidad y difícilmente alguien las responda. Has dejado una gran cantidad de código, y has olvidado explicar cuál es el problema o dificultad que estás teniendo con dicho código. Para evitar el cierre, podrías [edit] la pregunta, agregar una explicación de tu duda, dificultad o problema y reducir el código a lo esencial para poder reproducirlo.

Comment: Hola sureopossum7, bienvenido, para obtener una buena respuesta, es imprescindible formular una buena pregunta, esto implica, explicar claramente el problema, y adjuntar los códigos involucrados y los mensajes de error (si los huiera) ambos en formato texto, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta, y la adaptes a los requerimientos del sitio, y muestra que has intentado, para saber que formas parte de la resolución de tu problema,

Comment: Ya e realizado la modificacion